# Create opportunity record in target org from source org

Tags: rest-api, api, rest, salesforce-connect, salesforce-to-salesforce

My company is using two different Salesforce orgs (org1 and org2). I have a custom object in org1, called Tender__c. I want an automation to create an opportunity record in org2 when the Tender__c in org1 reaches the final stage. Is this possible?

I did some research on Salesforce connect, Salesforce-to-Salesforce, and other tools but could not find any solution. Also, I could not see the action 'RunFlowInAnotherOrg' in flow builder?

Could some please provide a link to any resource that could help me with this?

Comment: Take a look at [Data Integration](https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration) decision guide

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can execute logic on org2 directly from org1 without using Salesforce API. Salesforce has REST API to create records.
You can create Flow in org1 that will use Salesforce API on org2 with a help of the Apex code on org1.
The steps here are:

1. Create Invocable Apex on org1 that sends API request to org2 to create a record(it is also possible to create platform event or use custom endpoint on org2. custom endpoint needs to be implemented in Apex as well)
2. Create a Flow that uses Apex invocable to send request to org2
3. Test